# What is this tool for? Likely something to do with cables?

Tags: tools

I found this thing in a box of bicycle tool mix I got some time ago. In the end this was the only one I could not identify, so I am asking here: What is this thing and what is it used for, please? I think it might be somehow used to manipulate with the cables. But since I do not know the name of the tool, I can’t look up for more info

[image: Unknown tool]

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's a spoke wrench, for turning spoke nipples.  The benefit of this design is that, as opposed to the kind with an arm coming out each side of a central body, the force from your fingers is spread over the faces of the disk, meaning you can apply more force and it hurts less.

I'm not certain, because I haven't used it, but it also seems like it would be easier to keep your grip on the wrench; the other kind is prone to being fumbled and dropped as you turn it (at least when I'm the one turning it, it is).

Here's an example: [https://www.amazon.com/KLICKfix-Rixen-Kaul-SPOKEY-professional/dp/B003ZRWA4Y/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003ZRWA4Y)

Comment: Yeah, that’s it! Now I understand how it works. Thanks for a quick response!

Comment: A word of caution: It's not a one for all tool as spoke nipples come in different sizes and the tool has to be the correct size if you don't want to damage the nipples.

Comment: I would like to add that it is not so simple to tighten spokes. Care must be taken as you can offset the rim and/or make it worse.

Comment: @Tempus: Actually, tightening the spokes is the easy part. The tricky part is to do it in a way that the wheel stays true :-). This is called "truing" (or ["adjustment"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_wheel#Adjustment_.28.22truing.22.29)).

Comment: At least when I built wheels regularly, I found these much *less* comfortable than conventional spoke wrenches. You usually grip the edge of the wrench, and the "wings" in these are substantially thinner than on a conventional wrench. These can be handy in case of a seized nipple though (much more common with aluminium nipples than brass).

Comment: A fairly trivial point, but I rather like the more alliterative name _spoke spanner_.

Comment: @sleske , I am sure that is what I was implying. But thanks for making it more obvious as some might think it just a matter of tightening them was enough.

Comment: Yet another alternative name is a spoke key.

Comment: the brand name of the pictured item is "Spokey" (a fusion of the words 'spoke' and 'key').
the red ones were for standard euro/us spokes, yellow ones were for japanese standard spokes.